# PrimeFaces Calendar disabled, but doesn't look disabled

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar

I am using PrimeFaces6.1 widgetVar to disable various page elements.  I have several different types of elements on the page.  When they are all disabled, p:calendar is the only element that doesn't look disabled.

```
<p:calendar id="revision-date-from" value="#{search.revisionDateFrom}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="true" />---<p:calendar id="revision-date-to" value="#{search.revisionDateTo}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="true" />
```

I'm required to develop for Internet Explorer 11.

Does anyone else have this issue? Or may know how to solve this?  I guess, I could always play with the styling to change the bgcolor.  But it does seem odd that PrimeFaces would have this one outlier.

[Click here to see the image of elements p:calendar, p:inputText and p:selectOneMenu together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOKgS.png)

Comment: Why are you using client side `widgetVar` to `disable` the fields? Although, you can use `disabled` attribute on each of the fields!

Comment: I considered both ways.  The page that I'm working on has a lot of enabling and disabling of page elements (28 total elements) based on a combination of checkbox selections (14 checkboxes).  Doing this client side reduced the complexity of the implementation and I imagine will be more efficient since calls aren't going back to the server.

Comment: I solved this issue, I'll explain below.

Comment: Keep in mind that disabling client-side opens up a security hole. Clients can enable it!!!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this issue:  After doing research I learned that disabled PrimeFaces elements use a style class called 'ui-state-disabled' to assign a percentage of Opacity.  Inspecting the calendar element I discovered that 'ui-state-disabled' class was never assigned.  So, to solve my issue I overrode the class in my stylesheet. Well, didn't 'need' to do this, but I wanted to have control over all my disabled elements Opacity.

```
.ui-state-disabled {
    opacity: 0.45;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=45);
    cursor: default !important;
}
```

Using my widgetVar to disable I needed to add the class:

```
PF('widget_date').disable();
PF('widget_date').getJQ().addClass('ui-state-disabled');
```

Then to enable and remove the class:

```
    PF('widget_date').enable();
    PF('widget_date').getJQ().removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
```

This solution worked perfectly.

Comment: Ok, what PF version did you use? (next time always mention that from the start). And if it is latest, file an issue in github

Comment: Thank you Kukelje.  That was an oversight.  I edited my original with the version that I'm using and will file the issue as you suggested.